# how to make a c console program exit with exit function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){

    exit(0);

}
```

This is my code in c how could I make the console exit??I have tried to use the exit function but it seems like it doesn't work

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. The *console* (or shell) in which the program is run is completely independent of the program itself, it just provides a user I/O interface. Trying to kill the console sounds like bad design - instead, you should launch the program without attaching it to one (this is easy in a Unix environment, but trickier for Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` causes *your program* to exit, not the shell that you ran it from.  Your program is equivalent to:

```
int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

You might want to look into [`kill(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/kill/).

Editorial note: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: I think `kill` is Unix only. Asking about "console" rather than "shell" implies Windows.

Comment: Do you know how to do it on windows?

Comment: Nope. I just think that this is what he wants.

Comment: I guess `system()` with `taskkill`, or something?

Comment: @CarlNorum no, this won't help you as system only spawns a child-process from your process. I added some infos and links regadring a solution for Windows to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can't close the parent application with `exit`. `Exit` causes only your program to exit.

If you want to exit the parent application :

- On UNIX system, you can use [`Kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) combined with [`getppid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getppid).
- On windows you can achieve that with [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here is an example on how to [GetParentProcess](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9893/Get-Parent-Process-PID).
  But on Windows, I'm not sure you can, I think you will not have the right to kill the parent process. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx

  It seems that you can get the privilege to terminate a windows process :

  > [This knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131065) describes how to do it. You first call `SeDebugPrivilege()` to obtain the privileges to terminate processes, then you call [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` flag to get a handle to the process you wish to terminate, and then finally you call [`TerminateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx) to terminate the process.

  **EDIT:**
  *[Does not work because system launch a sub-shell]* It seems that you can achieve it with the [`system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4b6wz4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by calling simply `system("exit");`.

Comment: `system()` launches a sub-shell.

Comment: I was surprised too when I first learned it. But it makes sense when you remember the single-threaded nature of both C and console-applications.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to exit the console you started the process from, you have to get the parent process id ([`getppid`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getppid)) and then send a [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) signal.

In Windows you have to replicate the behavior of `getppid` by calls to [Process32First](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9893/Get-Parent-Process-PID) and Process32Next. Kill becomes [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can't...the program ends with exit(0); returning the exitcode to the caller...usually a command interpreter shell....which usually runs inside a terminal

the terminal will close if the program in it terminates....you can run your program directly inside a terminal, or use the shell to execute just one command

Answer (score 0):

Can't seem to track down the thread, but *years ago* I tried to answer this question in a usenet forum by suggesting `system("exit")` (which doesn't work, of course). But the correct answer at the time (mid-1990s) was to send the software interrupt to *reboot*. Protected-mode DOS (Dos in a Windows window) would intercept it and close the window.

If you want the program to *always close at exit*, you can edit the shortcut properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
#include <windows.h>

...
PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

Not sure if this works or not, but it is the first thing that comes to mind. You might substitute WM_CLOSE for WM_DESTROY instead.

Comment: You never send the `WM_DESTROY` message. Instead try calling `DestroyWindow(GetConsoleWindow())` and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

In order to exit from the console, you have to make a system call. It will be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("taskkill/IM cb_console_runner.exe");
{
```

Here, cb_console_runner.exe is the process name.

Resource : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)